# Specify colour to a stacked area graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

I would like to change specific colours (oder than rainbow default) to each column "Sector" in the code below

I've read that geom_area doesn't allow changes in colour? if so is there another way to plot this graph without using ggplot2 package?

```
Sector <- rep(c("S01","S02","S03","S04","S05","S06","S07"),times=7)
Year <- as.numeric(rep(c("1950","1960","1970","1980","1990","2000","2010"),each=7))
Value <- runif(49, 10, 100)
data <- data.frame(Sector,Year,Value)
data

ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Value, fill=Sector)) + 
  geom_area(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to change the color scale in ggplot.

Here's a way where you can specify exactly which colors you want:

```
Sector <- rep(c("S01","S02","S03","S04","S05","S06","S07"),times=7)
Year <- as.numeric(rep(c("1950","1960","1970","1980","1990","2000","2010"),each=7)) 
Value <- runif(49, 10, 100) 
data <- data.frame(Sector,Year,Value)
data

ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Value, fill=Sector)) + geom_area(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","blue","gray","orange","tan","purple","darkgray"))
```

Comment: thanks! and is it possible to add also colour gradients?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the variations of scale_fill_gradient